# Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am new to Transfer learning i am working on image classification of 2 categories. i am using InceptionV3, for classification of these images. My data
is in .jpg format. and folder structure is in below format.Since i have 2 categories i gave "binary_crossentropy" too. But facing issues.

> Parentfolder/train/categorie1
>   Parentfolder/train/categorie2
>
> Parentfolder/test/categorie1
>   Parentfolder/test/categorie2

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras import backend as K

# create the base pre-trained model
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
# and a logistic layer -- we have 2 classes
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)


for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# we chose to train the top 2 inception blocks, i.e. we will freeze
# the first 249 layers and unfreeze the rest:
for layer in model.layers[:249]:
   layer.trainable = False
for layer in model.layers[249:]:
   layer.trainable = True

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/Desktop/Transfer/train/',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'C:/Users/Desktop/Transfer/test/',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=1000,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
```

with:

```
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Or encode your target into columns, f.e. `[1,0,1]` is the same as `[[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]]`

Comment: Why 1? it suppose to be 2 right ?. I got 2 categories. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Two categories may be differently represented, as I showed in my example. One way is to use only two numbers {0,1} where 0 is the first category, and 1 is the second category. Another way is to use encoding, where [1,0] is the first class and [0,1] is the second one. Hope it helps, if not please make sure you understand the difference between softmax and sigmoid, and what is the categorical cross-entropy.